# C++ Constructor not found

Tags: c++, constructor

I've got this class defined on DateTime.h

```
class DateTime {
public:
    int h;
    int m;

    DateTime() {};
    DateTime(string & sf) {
        int i = sf.find(":", 0);
        string _h = sf.substr(0, sf.length() - i-1);
        string _m = sf.substr(i+1, sf.length() - i);

        h = atoi(_h.c_str());
        m = atoi(_m.c_str());
    };
}
```

Then in other module I include it like this

```
#include <DateTime.h>
```

And call the constructor like this

```
string str("12:13");
DateTime dt(str);
```

And gives me this error at compiling

```
src/problem/Reader.cpp: En la función miembro ‘void Reader::readFile(const char*)’:
src/problem/Reader.cpp:44:12: error: no hay coincidencia para la llamada a ‘(DateTime) (std::string&)’
make: *** [build/Reader.o] Error 1
```

Comment: It would be of great help if you could provide English error messages.

Comment: "No match for call to"

Comment: "In member function ...: No match for call to ..."

Comment: This compiles perfectly fine on my system. Can you provide a self-contained code example we can compile to replicate the error? Given that it's working on my system, I suspect the error is elsewhere.

Comment: Off-topic: Your "DateTime" type seems to be a "DayTime" (time of the day), not a "DateTime" (both date and time information); the name can be confusing.

Comment: Does it work when you use quotes to include DateTime? `#include "DateTime.h"`?

Comment: I will go out on a limb and say the two `string` types are not the same. One is `std::string`, the other... something else.

Comment: Never use `using` in header files. Be explicit in the header, only use `using` in the implementation file. That's for two reasons: The file including your header might have other using declarations (resulting in different types for `string`), and it might be the case that it doesn't want to use your using declarations (resulting in ambiguities).

Comment: Also note: The two semicolons after the constructor definitions are too much, and a semicolon after the class definition is missing. (The former is not critical and the latter might be a copy paste error.)

Comment: There is no real mistake in your code as you posted it here. You're hiding some context. Please try if this code snippet compiles with your compiler: http://ideone.com/fZ7NSA. My best guess is that you didn't show us the right code when you try to call the constructor. Or that the constructor is defined with something different than `std::string` (another `string` type)

Answer (score 4):

Your semi-colons are misplaced. The "};" should be the last one for the class. This is making the compiler not see the constructor that takes a string as a parameter.

Change it and try to compile it again and let us know.

Comment: It's not the braces but the semicolon that's misplaced in the OP's sample.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Move one brace and it's fixed :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just a matter of POV. Originally it was _'Your curly braces are misplaced ...'_

Answer (score 1):

Likely your string is const. Change the constructor

```
DateTime(string const& sf) {

// or even
DateTime(string sf) {
```

**Edit** It's either that, or indeed different `string` types.
I truly think my analysis makes more sense, statistically.

Comment: But that string in the client code snippet is not const: `string str("12:13");` (Although using non-const reference here is a bad idea.)

Comment: @sehe, I don't think that's the problem, the compile time error would be different.

Comment: @Miguel I bet you know that. My spanish (?) isn't up to par.

Comment: @leemes I'm out on a limb guessing that his actual code is not like that (it's potentially a class member used from a const member function, etc.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're missing several points here. That's an interesting thought, but his code shows otherwise. So, your guess is as good as anyones. Unless your spanish helped you with something the OP is not showing.